# Relation between android:onClick and View.OnClickListener s

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

Dabbling with Android Studio, and working through a few tutorials , but I don't understand a concept. Oh, and new to java too...haha.

1. Lets say I have a screen, an activity, `MainActivity.xml` with a button. 
   `MainActivity.xml` has an `onClick` attribute `goForIt` defined for the button.
2. In the `MainActivity` class I have a method `goForIt`.
   This is where the button being clicked will be responded to.
3. Inside that `goForIt` method, 
   I build an Intent to start another activity, 
   and fire it off by the statement `startActivity(intent)`

Questions:

1. Why do I need a listener? (If I do)? The `MainActivity.xml` is an explicit directive to a specific method. Or is that a "listener"?
2. What's the role of the manifest in this? The activity is there... but for what purpose? Again, being able to find the class and method is pretty explicit without any need to consult a lookup like the manifest....?
3. I'm confused by the Activity XML having an explicit attribute to a specific method in the class, and then at the same time, the Listener saying that if the onClick happens, then do something... they are both trying to do the same thing are they not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a single question that has a answer, but rather a set of different doubts from someone who starts Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is waaay to wide and should be (probably will be) closed.

But, here goes:

1. onClick attribute in xml file is a shortcut for creating a listener (the listener in such case gets created behind your back). You either use that, or a listener done by hand.
2. Manifest has no role in this (pressing the button). But it is necessary to configure the activity so that it starts when the launcher icon is pressed (among many other things).
3. Android API looks as if it was never properly designed... it just grew and evolved. So yes, there are multiple, confusing ways to do a single thing.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. I could have probably phrased my question a lot better, but my lack of experience makes it difficult to find the right terminology. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use listener or you can specify a method in xml to listen to the click on a view. In both you can the view as the parameter.

2.Manifest file helps you for many purpose:
to specify which activity is to be launched first
to get permissions for accessing internet, getting cal logs, using maps etc,
Specifying the theme or label for each activity and so and so ..

3.Both does the same thing. One is an alternative for other.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for: "Both does the same thing. One is an alternative for other"

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="goForIt"/>
```

and then

```
public void goForIt(View v) {
    startActivity(...)
}
```

is exactly the same thing that using:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(...)
    }
});
```

The first option is just a workaround, a short path to have the same effect.
Internally, it is just doing things the second way - take the button, add a click listener to it, and run it as soon as the user clicks on the button.

When your layout is inflated (after you call `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)`) the attribute android:onClick gets internally converted into something like this:

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        goForIt(v);
    }
});
```

The only difference is that it does it for you.

The manifest has no role in this context.

Answer (score 0):

**Why do I need a listener? (If I do)? The MainActivity.xml is an explicit directive to a specific method. Or is that a "listener"?**

Think you have 10 buttons where click is required, so Listener can handle all those types of button click.

**What's the role of the manifest in this? The activity is there... but for what purpose? Again, being able to find the class and method is pretty explicit without any need to consult a lookup like the manifest....?**

From manifest Android ( application manager ) understands things about your app like, which page is 1st or launcher page.

**I'm confused by the Activity XML having an explicit attribute to a specific method in the class, and then at the same time, the Listener saying that if the onClick happens, then do something... they are both trying to do the same thing are they not?**

yes they are doing same thing, try to use listener for them.